# add_widget and remove_widget for a class in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Im new to Kivy, Im sorry for asking 2 questions in a post..

First, why the `remove_widget()` does not work? It said `AttributeError: 'MyCard' object has no attribute 'remove_card'` but I tried to put them in other classes and it still does not work.

Second, why my widgets are still have "focus behavior" and my buttons are still clickable even when I put a card whose color has little transparent on it

This is my main.py file

```
class MyCard(Screen):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def add_card(self):
        self.add_widget(MyCard())
    def remove_card(self):
        self.remove_widget(MyCard(name='cardd'))

class AVCard(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        def build(self):
    sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition(duration=0.2))
    sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home'))
    sm.add_widget(AVCard(name='av'))
    return sm
```

and this is my home.kv file (AVCard class has its own .kv file)

```
<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home'
    MDIconButton:
        on_release: root.add_card()
        ...

<MyCard>:
    name: 'cardd'
    MDCard: #-> I put this card is to not allow user click on widgets behind it but it does not work
        md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, .3
        ...
    MDCard: #-> Thís card is like a window which includes small widgets in it
        ...
        Screen:
            MDIconButton: #-> The close button
                icon: "close-circle"
                ...
                on_release:
                    root.remove_card()
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `kv`, the `root.remove_card()` is trying to reference the `remove_card()` method of `root`. In this instance `root` refers to the root of the rule in which it appears, which is the `MyCard`. That is why you see the error message, the `remove_card()` is not in the `MyCard` object. The fix is to use a reference to the correct object that does contain the `remove_card()` method, like this:

```
<MyCard>:
    MDCard: #-> I put this card is to not allow user click on widgets behind it but it does not work
        md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, .3
    MDCard: #-> Thís card is like a window which includes small widgets in it
        Screen:
            MDIconButton: #-> The close button
                icon: "close-circle"
                on_release:
                    app.root.get_screen('home').remove_card(root)
```

Note the use of `app.root.get_screen('home').remove_card(root)`, this gets a reference to the `HomeScreen` object (assuming the `name` used is `home`), and calls its `remove_card()` method with `root` (the `MyCard` instance) as an arg.

Then , in the `HomeScreen` class, the `remove_card()` method can be:

```
def remove_card(self, card):
    self.remove_widget(card)
```

Comment: my `HomeScreen` id is `home` and I used `app.root.get_screen('home').remove_card()` like you, but when I clicked on close button, it didn't disappear..

Comment: Your `Screens` should each have a `name` attribute (not talking about `ids` here).

Comment: It still does not work.. Im sorry for my stupid, sir..  updated my code, can you take a look?.. thank you very much.

Comment: See updated answer.